# Закрытие tcp соединения GO

Tags: golang, tcp

Имеется TCP соединение между клиентом и сервером, клиент отправляет сообщение на сервер и получает ответ от сервера. Можно ли каким нибудь образом закрыть соединение, к примеру клиент отправляет exit и соединение закрывается.

Код сервера:

```golang
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "strings" // only needed below for sample processing

func main() {

  fmt.Println("Launching server...")
  ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
  conn, _ := ln.Accept()
  for {
    message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Message Received:", string(message))
    newmessage := strings.ToUpper(message)
    conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
  }
}
```

Код клиента:

```golang
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "os"

func main() {

  conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
  for { 
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Ваше сообщение: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, text + "\n")
    if text=="exit" {
        conn.Close()
    }
    message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("От сервера: "+message)
  }   
}
```

Comment: добавьте `text = text[:len(text)-1] ` после чтения строки в вашем клиенте это удалит `\n` и наслаждайетсь ошибками :). Подсказка никогда не опускайте проверку `if err!=nil {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант решения для вашей задачи "два в одном". Я постарался закоментировать изменения.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    // выбираем сервер или клиент

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage:\n %s server|client\n", os.Args[0])
        return
    }
    mode := strings.ToLower(os.Args[1])

    modes := map[string]func(){
        "server": runServer,
        "client": runClient,
    }
    run := modes[mode]

    // жалуемся
    if run == nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "expecting one of [client|server], found: %s\n", mode)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Usage:\n %s server|client\n", os.Args[0])
        return
    }

    // выполняем
    run()
}

func runServer() {
    fmt.Println("Launching server...")
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error listening: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        fmt.Println("Waiting for connection...")
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error accepting: %v\n", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("New connection. Waiting for messages...")

        go func(conn net.Conn) { // обрабатываем в го рутине чтобы мы могли общаться с кучей клиентов
            defer conn.Close()

            fmt.Printf("Serving new conn %v\n", conn)

            connReader := bufio.NewReader(conn) // ридер создается один раз

            for {
                message, err := connReader.ReadString('\n')
                if err != nil {
                    if err == io.EOF {
                        fmt.Printf("Connection %v closed.\n", conn)
                        break
                    }
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error reading from conn: %v\n", err)
                    break
                }
                message = strings.TrimSpace(message) // удаляем \n и \r

                fmt.Printf("From: %v Received: %s\n", conn, string(message))

                newmessage := strings.ToUpper(message)
                _, err = conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error writing to conn: %v\n", err)
                    break
                }
            }

            fmt.Printf("Done serving client %v\n", conn)
        }(conn)
    }
}

func runClient() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error dialing tcp: %v\nServer needs to be runing before client.\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // ридеры следует создавать один раз а не для каждого сообщения
    console := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    connReader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

    for {
        fmt.Print("Ваше сообщение: ")
        text, err := console.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error reading string: %v", err)
            return
        }
        text = strings.TrimSpace(text) // удаляем \n

        fmt.Fprintf(conn, text+"\n")
        if text == "exit" {
            fmt.Println("Закрываем соединение")
            return
        }

        message, err := connReader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error reading from conn: %v", err)
            return
        }
        message = strings.TrimSpace(message) // удаляем \n
        fmt.Printf("От сервера: %s\n", message)
    }

}
```

Comment: Запускаю код, но все равно при отправке exit соединение не закрывается

Comment: "Закрываем соединение" выходит?

Comment: Если я вручную закрываю клиента, то выходит надпись на сервере, что соединение разорвано, но если с клиента отправить сообщение exit, то ничего не происходит

Comment: В клиенте после `fmt.Fprintf(conn, text+"\n")` добавьте `fmt.Printf("%#x\n", text)`. Клиент должен писать `0x65786974`. Если печатает что-то другое в этом проблема. У меня догадка вы на атомате печатаете пробел до или после exit.

Comment: На клиенте выходит 0x657869740d. Я печатаю текст exit,  и после нажимаю enter. Больше ничего. Но соединение все равно не закрывается

Comment: Ок баг между клавитурой и стулом! %) Вы на Виндозе. Т.е. enter это `\r\n`! Я изменил код должно работать... Мой баг.